# nifi Loading file without polling

Tags: apache-nifi, polling

I'm new to using this tool to work on cloudera.

We need to upload files from an FTP folder to an HDFS folder.
The basic flow is defined with the classic getSFTP and putHDFS processors.

My question now is the following.
Is it possible that nifi does a one-time upload of data without the polling option?
Is there any way to disable polling?

Thank you for your attention
Daniele Consalvo
Infordata Analytics Team

Answer (score 0):

ListSFTP -> FetchSFTP -> PutHDFS

You can configure ListSFTP to run on a schedule - but if you really only want it to run once then:

- Start FetchSFTP & PutHDFS
- Use 'Run Once' on ListSFTP

The List will run once, then stop.